# integral over cartesian product of 3-spheres

Tags: integration, analysis, contour-integration

Let $\mathbb{S}^3\subset\mathbb{R}^4$ be the 4-dimensional sphere and consider its Cartesian product $\mathbb{S}^3\times\mathbb{S}^3\subset\mathbb{R}^8$. How can we integrate a function $h:\mathbb{R}^8\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$? What I'm really asking is how can we parametrize $\mathbb{S}^3\times\mathbb{S}^3$ if we know a parametrization of $\mathbb{S}^3$?
**Context**: $h:\mathbb{H}^2\cong\mathbb{R}^8\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is an harmonic function w.r.t. each quaternionic variable, so I'm trying to understand how harmonic function's properties translate in this setting. Does it still hold a mean value property?
I hope I've been sufficiently clear. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, this is the way.
If $\phi:M\rightarrow A$ parametrizes $A$ and $\psi:N\rightarrow B$ parametrizes $B$, then a parametrization of $A\times B$ is $\phi\times\psi:M\times N\rightarrow A\times B$, $(\phi\times\psi)(x,y):=\phi(x)\psi(y)$.
Thus, if $\psi:[0,\pi]\times[0,\pi]\times[0,2\pi]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^4$ defined by $\varphi(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3):=(\cos(\theta_1),\sin(\theta_1)\cos(\theta_2),\sin(\theta_1)\sin(\theta_2)\cos(\theta_3),\sin(\theta_1)\sin(\theta_2)\sin(\theta_3))$, then a parametrization of $\mathbb{S}^3\times\mathbb{S}^3$ can be the following
\begin{equation*}
\psi_1\times\psi_2:([0,\pi]\times[0,\pi]\times[0,2\pi])\times ([0,\pi]\times[0,\pi]\times[0,2\pi])\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^8
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
(\psi_1\times\psi_2)((\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3),(\varphi_1,\varphi_2,\varphi_3)):=(\cos(\theta_1),\sin(\theta_1)\cos(\theta_2),\sin(\theta_1)\sin(\theta_2)\cos(\theta_3),\sin(\theta_1)\sin(\theta_2)\sin(\theta_3),\cos(\varphi_1),\sin(\varphi_1)\cos(\varphi_2),\sin(\varphi_1)\sin(\varphi_2)\cos(\varphi_3),\sin(\varphi_1)\sin(\varphi_2)\sin(\varphi_3)).
\end{equation*}
Since the area factor is $||\det(J_\psi\times J_\psi^t)||=r^3\sin^2(\theta_1)\sin(\theta_2)$, the integral over $\mathbb{S}^3\times\mathbb{S}^3$ becomes
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\mathbb{S}^3\times\mathbb{S}^3}h(\alpha_1,\beta_1,\gamma_1,\delta_1,\alpha_2,\beta_2,\gamma_2,\delta_2)d\mathcal{H}^3\times\mathcal{H}^3=\int_{([0,\pi]\times[0,\pi]\times[0,2\pi])^2}h(\psi_1(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3),\psi_2(\varphi_1,\varphi_2,\varphi_3))\sin^2(\theta_1)\sin(\theta_2)\sin^2(\varphi_1)\sin(\varphi_2)d\theta_1d\theta_1d\theta_3d\varphi_1d\varphi_2d\varphi_3.
\end{equation*}